# Try catch for parameters during creating object in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following code that i get and parse data from linkedin api

```
Experience.objects.get_or_create(user=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id),
                          company=company,
                          title=i.find('title').text,
                          start_month=i.find('start-date').find('month').text,
                          start_year=i.find('start-date').find('year').text,
                          end_month=i.find('end-date').find('month').text,
                          end_year=i.find('end-year').find('year').text,
                          description=i.find('summary').text)
```

But date values like end_month and end_year are not mandatory in linkedin and also in my DB. But when i use the code it says

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

because position does not have an start_month in xml.

So i should check if i can get end_month or end_year from xml, and if not i will create the object with null end_year.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to do everything in one logical line. Compute your values first, and only after that create an object using those values. Your code will become much simpler, and your question will suddenly be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set the values to None if they're not present in linkedin's data, e.g.

```
if i.find('end-date')
    end_month = i.find('end-date').find('month').text
else:
    end_month = None

if i.find('end-year'):
    end_year = i.find('end-year').find('year').text
else:
    end_year = None

Experience.objects.get_or_create(
    user=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id),
    company=company,
    title=i.find('title').text,
    start_month=i.find('start-date').find('month').text,
    start_year=i.find('start-date').find('year').text,
    end_month=end_month,
    end_year=end_year,
    description=i.find('summary').text)
```

Does linkedin provide a unique id with their data? If so you should store that in your database and use it to identify the `Experience` object - otherwise if something changes at their end you'll end up with duplicates in your database.

Comment: yea this is also what i did. I hope there was some better way

Answer (score 0):

Yep you can do this if you want to avoid try:

```
Experience.objects.get_or_create(
    user=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id),
    company=company,
    title=i.find('title').text,
    start_month=i.find('start-date').find('month').text,
    start_year=i.find('start-date').find('year').text,
    end_month=i.find('end-date') and i.find('end-date').find('month').text,
    end_year=i.find('end-year') and i.find('end-year').find('year').text,
    description=i.find('summary').text
)
```

Note the

```
i.find('end-date') and i.find('end-date').find('month').text
```

will return

```
i.find('end-date').find('month').text
```

if

```
i.find('end-date')
```

is not None.

I think this fits your needs.